# nats message queue - ack a message from jetstream consumer in a separate request

Tags: node.js, nats.io

Is it possible to manually acknowledge delivered message stream sequence in a separate request (independent on the request receiving the message) to the nats server?

Usually you would receive messages from a consumer, process them and ack them in a single defined context:

```js
    const messages = await consumer.consume({ max_messages: maxMessages });

    for await (const m of messages) {
        //some process logic
        await m.ack();
    }
```

In my use case I want to bridge http API with a nats stream of messages.
I defined two http endpoints:
- `GET /events` which would pull messages from a pull consumer.
- `POST /events/ack?lastReceivedEventSeqId=10` which would acknowledge with the `nats` server that the messages up to the message with sequence id `10` have been successfully processed.

The issue is I can not `ack` a message after I loose the context that initially received the message from nats server.

```js
    //inside implementation of GET /events/ack endpoint`
    const s : Stream | undefined = await jetstream.streams.get('mystream');
    const message = await s.getMessage({seq: 10});
    //message has no `ack` method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NATS.io JetStream `ack` is used to let [Consumer](https://docs.nats.io/using-nats/developer/anatomy#stream-consumers) know that the given message was successfully processed by the client and does not need to be redelivered.

Consumer is a separate construct on the server that can be treated as a `view` or a `pointer` into a Stream.
A Stream can have hundreds of Consumers, each going trough messages at its own pace, with its own config, starting sequence, deliver policy etc. And it's Consumers who handle acks for their progress through a Stream.

If you're using `direct get`, which is what `streams.get()` does in the javascript NATS library, it retrieves a message directly from a stream, without a consumer or any additional state on the server side. Hence there is no point in acknowledging it, as `Stream` does not track progress of going through its messages. You're just getting a single message. You either got it or not. It is enough to check the error of that `get` operation.